# How to fit router-link exacly to image? Vue js 3

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, routerlink

I have implemented a flex grid gallery and I want to make images router-links to other sites. You can see that the entire `gallery-item` is a link, how can I make it only an image?
 [image]

vue component .vue

```
<template>
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-item">
            <router-link to="/cat"><img src="../assets/cat.jpg" alt="cat"></router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

css styling

```
<style scoped>
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.gallery-item {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  max-height: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `router-link` a class and make it as `display: block`, or you can merge:

```js
<template>
    <div class="gallery">
        <router-link to="/cat" class="gallery-item">
            <img src="../assets/cat.jpg" alt="cat">
        </router-link>
    </div>
</template> 

<style scoped>
    .gallery {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
      grid-gap: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
    }
    .gallery-item {
        background-color: aquamarine;
        max-height: 300px;
        display: block;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work. Why it should?

Comment: I want the link to be a image, not a gallery-item